# Facebook dialog request cause a popup blocker. Even with user action

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup-blocker

I have the following script to activate the facebook dialog screen after a button is pressed. Although there is some user action, the popup is still blocked. I searched a lot about this problem but i can't figure out how to solve this :( I hope someone can help me out!

The script is triggered by a button with:

```
onClick="fb_callout();
```

Script:

```
    <div id="facebook-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '', // App ID from the App Dashboard
     channelUrl : '', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    //display: 'iframe',
    name: '', 
    link: '', 
    picture: '', 
    caption: '', 
    description: '' 
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      window.location.href = '';
    } else {
      alert('');
    }
  }
);

  };

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 function fb_callout() {
     (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
     }
</script>
```

With your (CBroe's) instructions I changed the script a bit. And now it seems to work! :)
The popup window appears without problems.

Result:

```
<div id="facebook-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here


  };

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function fb_callout()
    {

    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: '', // name of the product or content you want to share
    link: '', // link back to the product or content you are sharing
    picture: '', // path to an image you would like to share with this content
    caption: '', // caption
    description: '' // description of your product or content
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      window.location.href = '';
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You are loading the JS SDK onclick – but since this is done asynchronously, when the `fbAsyncInit` event is handled, there is no connection to that click the user made any more, and therefor the browser blocks the popup as a not user-initiated one.

Comment: Thnx for your answer! I'm pretty new with Javascript. Can you explain how to make this script synchronously?

Comment: Why don’t you just load the SDK unconditionally, as is the usual way, and then just call `FB.ui` when the user clicks?

Comment: I'm going to give that a try. Another (maybe better) solution to my problem is that this script opens the facebook dialog in the same page (or a new one) instead of a popup. Should that be possible?

Comment: I posted a new version of the script. It seems everything is working fine now! Is this what you meant with loading the SDK unconditionally?